# Como somar valores de uma requisição:

Tags: python, api, request, python-requests

Exemplo:

```
request = requests.get('https://api.amountofsomething.com')
quantidade = requisição.json()['amount']
```

Essa requisição retorna a quantidade, por exemplo: `{[{25}{120}{158}{0}{2}{10}]}`

Eu preciso somar os valores sem padrões. Tentei dessa forma:

```
amount0 = amount[0]['amount']

amount1 = amount[1]['amount']

amount2 = amount[2]['amount']

sum0 = amount0+amount02
...
```

Para grandes quantidades de dados, o código ficará demasiado. Tentei destas formas:

```
sum0 =  amount [0+2]['amount']

sum1 = amount [[1] + [18]]['amount']

sum2 = amount [0]['amount'] + amount [1]['amount']
```

Nenhuma dessas opções funcionou. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Não percebi essa forma de somar ou esse formato de dados da quantidade, por isso não vou colocar resposta mas sim fazer uma sugestão com base no que percebi (acho). Baseando-me na tua primeira tentativa, tenta `sum(amount['amount'] for amount in request.json())`, baseado na tua tentativa acredito que possas fazer isto https://ideone.com/dbKFMu

Comment: Também não consegui entender o que precisas. Podes [edit] a pergunta colocando o retorno completo da requisição e descrever qual o resultado desejado?

Comment: Coloque o valor de retorno da requisição tal como vem  - o que está no seu exemplo não é JSON válido, nem Python - e não tem como fazer nada, já que não está correto.

Programação não é mágica, nem chute. `[{"amount": 30}, {"amount":50}]` é completamente diferente de `[{30, 50}]` ou de  `[{30},{50}]`.